# php sql display datas in javascript using php

Tags: php, javascript, sql, database

I have an issue with java script. I am working on an application. Its a event booking system. In front end i use javascript. I just collect the data and insert to database by php. Now the problem is i cant fetch the datas from database and display in front end **more than one  column.**
I tried both while and for loop. but it simply display only one column. In this i just include php out put into the javascript codes...please help me any one..
file is

```
$_selc_content =mysql_query("select * from astro_booking WHERE astro_id = '9' order by id ASC");
while($_static_row = mysql_fetch_object($_selc_content))
    {
?>
```

javascript file is

```
return {   
    events : [          
        {
                "id":<?php echo $_static_row->id; ?>,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day + <?php echo $final_start_date; ?>, <?php echo $start_time; ?>, <?php echo $start_min_final; ?>),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day + <?php echo $final_end_date; ?>, <?php echo $end_time; ?>, <?php echo $end_min_final; ?>),
           "title":"<?php print_r($_static_row->title); ?>",
           "body":"<?php echo $_static_row->body; ?>",

}
```

The javascript sample code is

```
{
    "id":1,
    "start": new Date(year, month, day, 12),
    "end": new Date(year, month, day, 13, 30),
    "title":"Lunch",

},
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be better to copy php array to js array and then you can work only with js array. In order to do that, you can use php json_encode() function.
What do you think?